# Selecting Different rows if the values of one column are equal

Tags: sql-server, toad

I am trying to write a SQL query that selects the top 4 from a random query so I can do quality checks on the certain cases. Each case has an account number tied to a client. The problem is that each case has a unique number but may have the same account number.

What I am looking to do is if the account number is the same on two cases to have the SQL select a new row with a different account number.

```
Select Top 4
    Account,
    CaseNum
From dbo.tblRequest
Where LoggedDate Between GetDate() - 7 and GetDate() - 1 
Order By NewId();
```

The Results will display 4 accounts but at times it is possible that the same account is displayed twice. As stated I want to only display distinct accounts for a 7 day period.

I have tried the distinct key word and it still displays the accounts twice in some queries results.

Answer (score 1):

Try following statement. using row_number to get only on line for same accountNumber.

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        Select 
            Account,
            CaseNum,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY GETDATE()) AS rn
        From dbo.tblRequest
        Where LoggedDate Between GetDate() - 7 and GetDate() - 1 
    ) AS t WHERE t.rn=1
    Order By
    NewId()
```

Comment: This worked thank you for the help I have been working on this all day.